# Obtaining minimal index of dataframe, when crossed specific value

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider three dataframes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(42)
first_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100))
top_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100))
bottom_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100))
```

And one frame for labeling:

```
label_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(100))
```

I want to fill label_frame in the following way:

1. If `first_frame[0:5] > top_frame[0]` (exceeded `top_frame[0]`) and `first_frame[0:5] >= bottom_frame[0]` (does not exceed bottom frame), then we label this as 1
2. If `first_frame[0:5] <= top_frame[0]` (does not exceed `top_frame[0]`) and `first_frame[0:5] < bottom_frame[0]` (exceed bottom frame), then we label this as -1
3. If `first_frame[0:5] > top_frame[0]` (exceeded `top_frame[0]`) and `first_frame[0:5] < bottom_frame[0]` (exceed bottom frame), then we assign it as 1, if we firstly cross the top frame, and -1 when we firstly cross the bottom frame (for example, we assign 1, when we cross the first_frame at point 2, and we crossed bottom frame at point 4).
4. We assign 0 if we don't cross any - top or bottom frame
5. We apply this for whole dataframe i.e. then we apply exactly the same algorithm for `first_frame[1:6]` and `top_frame[1]`, `bottom_frame[1]`, then for `first_frame[2:7]` and `top_frame[2]` and `bottom_frame[2]`.

**My work so far**

I want to do this by applying `.rolling` function (I think is the most elegant way to do it). I found in some question asked today, that what is possible is to have:

```
first_frame.rolling(5, min_periods = 5).max().shift(-4) > top_frame
first_frame.rolling(5, min_periods = 5).min().shift(-4) < bottom_frame
```

This code checks if maximum of those numbers exceeded top_frame, and if minimum of those numbers exceeded bottom_frame. The problem is that when we have both frames exceeded, I don't know how to say, that it should return the index of the first top/bottom frame crossed.

Do you have any idea how it can be done? I tried to write custom function to combine it with `apply`, but I'm not sure how it should look like

***Example**

```
first_frame[0:5] > top_frame.iloc[0]
      0
0  True
1  True
2  True
3  True
4  True

first_frame[0:5] < bottom_frame.iloc[0]
      0
0  False
1   True
2  False
3  False
4   True
```

As we observe, the first observation already crossed the `top_frame`, however, in the case of `bottom_frame` the second observation crossed it. We should label it as 1, since first `top_frame` was crossed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a Dataframe here and not a Series? In your example `top_frame[0]` returns the full column `0` and `top_frame[1]` throws a KeyError, as there is no column called `1`.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, it was just an example, of course it should be `top_frame.iloc[0]` etc

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "crossing" a dataframe? Could you provide an example that also shows expected result? (Perhaps with hardcoded values and a shorter window)

Comment: I updated the question with an example. Hope its clear rn ;))